# how to extract ios firmware from catalyst 3560 v2

Tags: cisco-catalyst

i accidentally formatted my client cisco catalyst 3560 v2 24 ps. Now no firmware inside. Lucky i got another same switch for standby. my question here, how to backup firmware from standby switch to my client switch? im new in this field.perhaps any 1 can give instruction to help...btw, the firmware is flash:/c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-58.SE2/c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-58.SE2.bin. ty

Comment: Actually, that is the OS (IOS). The ROMON is more akin to firmware. I don't think you would call Windows firmware; more likely, you would call the BIOS firmware.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Source Healthy Switch : A

Destination Unhealthy Switch : B

On the A switch;

> A(config)#tftp-server flash:/c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-58.SE2/c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-58.SE2.bin

On the B Switch ;

Enter the Rommon (Hint: Ctrl + Brk)

> rommon 1> set
>
> rommon 2> IP_ADDRESS=192.168.X.X    (B Switch IP address Temporary)
>
> rommon 3> IP_SUBNET_MASK=X.X.X.X    (B Switch Mask)
>
> rommon 4> DEFAULT_GATEWAY=X.X.X.X   (Default Gateway IP)
>
> rommon 5> TFTP_SERVER=X.X.X.X       (A Switch IP address)
>
> rommon 6> TFTP_FILE=c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-58.SE2.bin
>
> rommon 7> tftpdnld
>
> Invoke this command for disaster recovery only.
>
> WARNING: all existing data in all partitions on flash will be lost! Do you wish to continue?
>   y/n:  [n]:  **y**
>
> rommon 8> reset

Comment: I'm not too sure if tftpdnld is available in some of the Cisco switches. As a backup you may have to use a serial console to transfer a file to your switch using xmodem transfer. Link:- https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/70104-transfer-an-ios-image-over-a-console-cable